# I have problem in my Vue.js code, i am getting errors while inserting data into database

Tags: validation, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

I am getting 3 different errors while submitting the data from the form

first error is : [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.getAllUsers is not a function"

and then if I test form validation without typing anything validation works but i get this error: [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined"

and then i fill in all the fields and click the submit button then i get this error: [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: axios is not defined"

Note: my API works perfectly

here's my code

this is the form

```
<template>
  <b-container>
    <div class="update-info">
      <div class="feature-text myinv-title">
        <h5 class="title title-sm">Update your information</h5>
      </div>
      <form id="app" @submit="saveUser" method="post" novalidate="true">

    <p v-if="errors.length">
      <b>Please fill in all the fields</b>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="error in errors" class="alert alert-danger">{{ error }}</li>
      </ul>
    </p>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="trx">TRX Address No.</label>
        <input
          id="trx"
          class="form-control trx-address-nooverflow"
          v-model="myAddress"
          type="text"
          name="TRX Address"
          readonly
        >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input
          id="name"
          class="form-control"
          v-model="name"
          type="text"
          name="name"
        >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="name">Country</label>
        <country-select
         id="Country"
         class="form-control"
         v-model="country"
         :country="country"
         topCountry="US" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="email">Email ID</label>
        <input
          id="email"
          class="form-control"
          v-model="email"
          type="email"
          name="email"
        >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="email">Mobile No</label>
        <input
          id="mobile"
          class="form-control"
          v-model="mobile_no"
          type="text"
          name="mobile"
        >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <div class="top-30">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-btn btn-grad btn-submit" />
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </b-container>
</template>
```

this is the script

```
<script>
export default{
  data(){
    return{
    errorMessage: "",
    successMessage: "",
    errors: [],
    trx_no: "",
    name: "",
    country: "",
    email: "",
    mobile_no: "",
    myAddress: "",
    newUser: {trx_no: "", name: "", country: "", email: "", mobile: ""}
    }
  },
  mounted: function(){
    this.getAllUsers();
  },

  methods: {

    saveUser(event){
    event.preventDefault()

    this.checkForm()

    if(!this.errors.length) {
       var formData = this.toFormData(this.newUser);

        axios.post('http://localhost:8888/vue-and-php/public/api/update-info-form.php?action=update', formData, { crossdomain: true })
        .then((response) => {

          this.newUser = {trx_no: "", name: "", country: "", email: "", mobile: ""};

          if(response.data.error){
            this.errorMessage = response.data.message;
          }else{
            this.getAllUsers();
          }
          });
      }
    },
    toFormData: function(obj){
      var form_data = new FormData();
      for(var key in obj){
        form_data.append(key, obj[key]);
      }
      return form_data;
    },
    clearMessage: function(){
      this.errorMessage = "";
      this.successMessage = "";
    },
    //validation
    checkForm: function (e) {
      this.errors = [];

      if (!this.name) {
        this.errors.push("Name Required.");
      }
      if (!this.country) {
        this.errors.push("Country Required.");
      }
      if (!this.email) {
        this.errors.push('Email Required.');
      } else if (!this.validEmail(this.email)) {
        this.errors.push('Valid Email Address Required.');
      }
      if (!this.mobile_no) {
        this.errors.push("Phone Number Required.");
      }

      if (!this.errors.length) {
        return true;
      }

      e.preventDefault();
    },

    validEmail: function (email) {
      var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      return re.test(email);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I am also posting my PHP code just for reference

```
<?php

//Import Database

require 'base.php';


if(isset($_GET['action'])){
  $action = $_GET['action'];
}

//create
if($action == 'update'){

  $trx_number = $_POST['trx'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $country = $_POST['country'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $mobile = $_POST['mobile_no'];

  $result = $con->query(" INSERT INTO `update_information` (`id`, `trx_no`, `name`, `country`, `email`, `mobile_no`) VALUES (null,'$trx_number','$name','$country','$email','$mobile') ");
  if($result){
    $res['message'] = "Success";
  }else {
    $res['error'] = true;
    $res['message'] = "Error";
  }
  $res['update_information'] = $update_information;
  }
  $con->close();
 //encoding into json
  echo json_encode($res);
  die();
```

Comment: there is no any function defined named getAllUsers .
how are  you calling it without defining it

Comment: try this `<form id="app" @submit.prevent="saveUser" method="post" novalidate="true">` and remove `event.preventDefault()` from method.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the solutions to your errors

1. There is no method called `getAllUsers` You need to define one or stop calling it in your code.
2. Remove the `event.preventDefault()` from your code ande replace `@submit="saveUser"` with `@submit.prevent="saveUser"` in your form.
3. Import axios into your component with `import axios from 'axios'`. **NOTE:** Make sure axios ins installed in your project

Comment: Vue uses "prevent" as an event modifier, not "preventDefault"

Comment: hi prevent default wont work just "prevent" works but stilli am getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined"

Comment: use "prevent" and not "preventDefault"